# Magento add random items which are in stock or qty > 1

Tags: magento, random

I am looking to filter the items which are only in stock or qty >= 1.

My code:

```
$_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($this->getCategoryId());
$_productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
                   ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                   ->addAttributeToFilter('sku', array('gt' => 140));
$_productCollection->getSelect()->order(new Zend_Db_Expr('RAND()'));                  
$_productCollection->setPage(1, 8);
```

I was trying to add `->addAttributeToFilter('is_in_stock', '1');` but with no luck.

Comment: @user1139767 it might help others if you posted your answer below.